# Remove status 'archived' from the default post and page view

Tags: posts, filters, pages, wp-admin, tags

I have some page status on my wordpress platform :
All, mine, draft,published and ARCHIVED as you can see on the picture below

[image: wordpress pages status]

When i go to pages, default view is on **ALL pages** a got 62 pages on my exemple.

I want to hide archived page on the default view. So on **ALL(62)** i want to see all pages except Archived status pages. The **archived** pages must still be visible if we go to **Archived tab**.

I want to filter only draft and published pages, so i tried this URL on the browser :

**website/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=publish+draft&post_type=page**

But it doesn't work.

Thanks for help.

Comment: WordPress does not feature an "Archived" status. Are you using a plugin to add this?

Comment: yes i added archived status and i want to hide it from all status view page